# Is this limit zero?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, exponential-sums

Define $e(\theta)=e^{2\pi i\theta}, \theta\in [0,1]$, $P_n=\{p_1,p_2,...,p_n\}$ are the first $n$ primes, $\|f\|_1=\int_{[0,1]}|f(\theta)|d\theta$.

> Problem 1.
> is it true for all fixed $m\in \mathbb{N^*}$ that,
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{A\subset \mathbb{N^*}, |A|=m}\frac{\|\sum_{p_i\in P_n}\sum_{a_j\in A}e(p_ia_j\theta)\|_1}{n\|\sum_{a_j\in A}e(a_j\theta)\|_1}=\ \ \  0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ?$$

Because $m$ is fixed, this maybe can be solved by circle method, decompose $\mathbb{T}$ into the major arc and the minor arc, and estimate the major arc and the minor arc.
But I can not figure out the details. And if this Problem 1 is true, is the following one true? Which is a more effective one?

> Problem 2.
> Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{N^*}\to \mathbb{N^*}, f(n) \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$, such that,
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{A\subset \mathbb{N^*}, |A|=f(n)}\frac{\|\sum_{p_i\in P_n}\sum_{a_j\in A}e(p_ia_j\theta)\|_1}{n\|\sum_{a_j\in A}e(a_j\theta)\|_1}=\ \ \  0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ?$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "sequence tends to zero", or the "limit is zero", but the limit doesn't tend!

Comment: Okey, already corrected, thanks!

Comment: katago: The change still doesn't fix the issue identified by @YCor

Comment: Yemon Choi: I am sorry for my poor English.

Comment: @katago: The problem is with your notation, not your English. On the RHS, the relation $\to 0$ should be $=0$.  This is because the LHS is a number (namely the limit), not a sequence. Alternatively, omit the limit symbol on the LHS.

Comment: GH from MO: Thanks!